# How to evaluate $\sum_{k=1} ^{n-1} \frac{\sin (k\theta)}{\sin \theta}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

How to evaluate $$\sum_{k=1} ^{n-1} \frac{\sin (k\theta)}{\sin \theta}$$

Any help ? I tried to use difference method. But I'm not getting there.

Comment: Factor $1/\sin(\theta)$, then consider $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{ik\theta}$. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Use the [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities),

$$\cos((k-1)\theta)-\cos((k+1)\theta)=2\sin(k\theta)\sin(\theta)$$

and then sum the resulting telescoping series.

Comment: +1 Nice. This is what I have been trying to figure out :)

Comment: You're quite welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

For a different approach:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sin(k\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(k\theta)$$

$\Im$ means the imaginary part.

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\cos(k\theta)+i\sin(k\theta))$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{k\theta i}$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\frac{1-e^{n\theta i}}{1-e^{\theta i}}$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)}$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)}\cdot\frac{1-\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)}$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\frac{(1-\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta))(1-\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))}{(1-\cos(\theta))^2+\sin^2(\theta)}$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\frac{(1-e^{n\theta i})(1-e^{-\theta i})}{(1-\cos(\theta))^2+\sin^2(\theta)}$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\frac{1-e^{n\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}+e^{(n-1)\theta i}}{2(1-\cos(\theta))}$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\Im\frac{1-\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)-\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)+\cos((n-1)\theta)+i\sin((n-1)\theta)}{2(1-\cos(\theta))}$$

$$=\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\frac{-\sin(n\theta)+\sin(\theta)+\sin((n-1)\theta)}{2(1-\cos(\theta))}$$

You might be able to simplify that last line, but it's a well known solution.